# I need to draw a table in the file with python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python, I'm currently working on a project scheduler, I get the data entered by the user, then put them in a table in a file to print it later.

unfortunately I have no idea how to do it, I searched a lot on the internet without success.
So if someone can help me it would be really cool

Comment: This would be a good starting point. Sqlite in python. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

your request seems rather broad and not overly specific so this answer may not be what you're looking for but I will try help anyway.

#### *Saving Files in Python*

If you want to learn about saving files look up a tutorial on *Pickle*. *Pickle* lets you save data while maintaining its data type, for example, you can save a list in a file using *Pickle* then load the file using *Pickle* to get the list back. To use *Pickle* make sure to have the line `import pickle`at the top of your code and use `pickle.` before every *Pickle* function. `e.g. pickle.dump()`

Here's a useful tutorial I found on *Pickle* https://pythonprogramming.net/python-pickle-module-save-objects-serialization/

You will also want to ensure you know about file handling in Python. Here's a cheat sheet with all the basic file handling functions https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-file-handling

#### *Dates and Times in Python*

A helpful module called *Datetime* will enable you to check your system's current Date and/or Time in Python. There are many functions of *Datetime* however you will probably only need to use the basic aspects of it. Again make sure you have the line `import datetime` at the top of your code and use `dattime` before every *Datetime* function.

Here's a useful tutorial I found on *Datetime* https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_date_time.htm

If you find yourself stuck or you're not sure what to do feel free to ask more questions. Hope this has been somewhat helpful for you.